# phpMyAdmin Error #1043 Cannot log in to MySQL with root password (OS X 10.8.3)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, osx-mountain-lion

I am trying to log in to phpMyAdmin using my root password(Username: root Password: ******), but I always receive the error:

```
#1043 Cannot log in to the MySQL server.
```

I'm sure I know the root password, and I can log in to MySQL in terminal with the command:

`mysql -u root -p`

but if I log in using `mysqladmin -u root password ******` it shows

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

I would very much appreciate any help. My wits end with this problem. I tried many websites and instructions but they are useless.

My assignment relies on the PHP and MySQL environment, any advices or explanations would be helpful and I appreciate the assistance. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

That is because you need to use the following syntax:

```
mysqladmin -uroot -p***** (command here)
```

I had a similar problem and I solved it by setting a blank password for root and adding this to my config.inc:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
```

Then, when I successfully logged in, I changed my root password within the web based GUI.

Hope this helps.